# WP7 Push Notification Server in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, push-notification

This helper library was published by Microsoft for Push Notifications in WP7.
http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/01/14/windows-push-notification-server-side-helper-library.aspx

The server is implemented as a WPF application though.  Has anyone tried to create a silverlight application instead of the WPF sample. Any jump start on this is appreciated?

Pratik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code wise it will be the same. The only problem I see is that the Silverlight app and the services will need to be in same domain else cross domain file is needed for the Silverlight to connect to the service.